# AdMob not work on real device

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I've used this guide for display an AdMob Banner in my app
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start
My problem is that the AdMob banner is only shown on my test device like this
[image]
But on real device I don't see anything
My dependencies in gradle file is:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my code:

```
MobileAds.initialize(getContext(), "ca-app-pub-****");
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("4F8D70E24813A8C1CFF9B07A47A4F484")
            .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template")
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(request);
```

And this is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.saffru.colombo.navigationdrawervideotutorial.MainFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/l_apos_onomastico_di_oggi"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/xxx"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textColor="@color/verde1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp" />

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-****">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

It doesn't work.

This is a screenshot [image] of my app.

My code is

```
MobileAds.initialize(getContext(), "ca-app-pub-6864438797370510/3840785983");

AdView mAdView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And in my AdMob account I see this 
[image]

If I add .addTestDevice("***")
My logcat is

```
02-19 22:07:28.379 2762-2762/com.saffru.colombo.onomastici2 W/System: 
ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000e/n/armeabi-v7a
02-19 22:07:28.380 2762-2762/com.saffru.colombo.onomastici2 W/System: 
ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000e/n/armeabi
02-19 22:07:28.392 2762-2762/com.saffru.colombo.onomastici2 
I/FirebaseCrashApiImpl: FirebaseCrashApiImpl created by ClassLoader 
p[DexPathList[[zip file"
/data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000e/
DynamiteModulesC_GmsCore_prodmnc_xxhdpi_release.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories[/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/
app_chimera/m/0000000e/n/armeabi-v7a, 
/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000e/n/armeabi, 
/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]
02-19 22:07:29.145 2762-2762/com.saffru.colombo.onomastici2 W/System: 
ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000c/n/armeabi
02-19 22:07:29.230 2762-2878/com.saffru.colombo.onomastici2 W/System: 
ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000c/n/armeabi
02-19 22:07:29.295 2762-2888/com.saffru.colombo.onomastici2 D/OpenGLRenderer: 
Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
```

Comment: share logs from your device.. you adUnitId might be incorrect, try changing it with new id?

Comment: I add my logcat

Answer (score 1):

This code for testing the admob ads. I think, You followed the test ads tutorial.

You need to create you own app in the admob account and include your ad-unit in initialize part.

The reference link : https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3052638

Your activity code.

```
            MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "Your own admob ad-unit");

            AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

These four line is enough. Other than this everything is fine.

Note: Don't test your real admob ad-unit. If so, There is chance to terminate your admob account by google.

You need to use your real ad-unit when you release app in play store.

Comment: I've just created an AdMob account, in my code I put the app id taken from app management page in AdMob.

Comment: You mean ad-unit? Have you changed the code like those 4 lines? Then, Generate signed app i.e release build and post your app in google play store. Then, Download from there and check.

Comment: I change the code with those four lines, and I have published the application. But how can I test it on a real device without that my account be deleted?

Comment: Just download on your device. The real ad will display. Don't click on those ads. You can see the ads. But, that too limited. Becoz, The ads publisher paid to google for those ads.  

Google doesn't gave certain norms about how developer test real ads. But, gave warning that don't test real ads. If do, They simply disabled your admob account and didn't give you the reason or next chance.

Comment: I think, They will link your google developer account and device's play-store account and matched like the developer tested the real ads. So, Download from some other device have different google account as play store account to test real ads. This method also not recommend one. But, either way don't click on ads. Because each click will count as ad hit in backend.

Comment: While publishing your app in play-store, have you authorize that this app contain ads. There is a option like this while publishing. Also share your logcat of activity while running.

Comment: I add my logcat

Comment: The added logcat doesn't gives me any clue. Try add some relevant logcat or warnings.

Comment: These are the only warning that I see when I run the application. Anyway, Google has deleted my admob account so I give up. 
Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Check your logs you will find an error saying to add your device as a test device using this line of code

```
`AdSettings.addTestDevice("You will find the Key in your logs");`
```